# Content loaded with jQuery ajax POST loses styling for a split second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a web app and in this app I sometimes load content with the jQuery ajax POST method. This works very good but there is a problem.

After successful POST I load the page content (page) that I get in return.
The problem with this is that when it "arrives" it is not styled and I can see the raw output for a split second and then the styling kicks in.

How can I avoid this "naked" moment?

This is my code:

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://example.com/resource/", 
    data: {image_id: image_id},
    beforeSend: function (html) {
        $('#sidebar').html('Loading');
    },
    success: function (html) {
      $('#sidebar').html(html);
    },
    error: function (html) {
        $('#sidebar').html('Something went wrong!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it hidden until all the data is in place, then show it with the content:

```
success: function (html) {
    $('#sidebar').hide().html(html).show();
},
```

Comment: I tried that but I does not help. 
$('#sidebar').hide();
$('#sidebar').html(html);
$('#sidebar').delay(1000).show();

Comment: @JonathanClark. Then maybe it needs more then one second...?

Comment: @JonathanClark. How does you page get it's style? If it with css there shouldn't be a problem with my answer as is. not `delay` needed.